# How to count total enable and disable row from one query?

Tags: sql

eg.

```
id name age status
1  aaa  10  1
2  bbb  20  0
3  ccc  30  1
```

Now how to count total status of 1 and 0 from single query.
Ans will be 1 => 2 and 0 => 1

Comment: What problem you faced in your attempt? Show your steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get one row, which is what I believe you are asking for, use conditional `SUM`s:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status0
FROM Table1
```

To get multiple rows, simply `GROUP BY` status:

```
SELECT status, COUNT(1) AS rows
FROM Table1
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: thanks your case example is best for me

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    STATUS, 
    COUNT(*) Total 
FROM 
    YourTable
GROUP BY STATUS
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    STATUS, 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY STATUS) Total 
FROM 
    YourTable
```